# Impersonation not working in scheduled task

Tags: windows-server-2003

FYI, this question has been [cross-posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5439594/impersonation-not-working-in-scheduled-task) from Stack Overflow.

I have a very simple program that copies files from one location to another, and I have scheduled its run everyday using the Windows scheduler.

1. When the scheduler launches it, it fails and logs:

   > System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '' is denied.
2. If I just launch the program by double clicking it, it fails with the same error as above.
3. When I run the program manually with "Run as" and use the same credential that I used in the Windows scheduler it runs successfully.

The credential used in all the three cases is the one that I use to login to the system.

Can anybody please help me in understanding why this is happening?

Comment: Please do not cross post between sites, this creates more noise and confusion.  Thanks!

Comment: Just a random thing I found googling, can you give the permissions to the NETWORK SERVICE user instead of whatever the current user is?